# how to get the version number of a tag in a list

Tags: python

I am trying to grep "INCLUDED IN TEAM_COM_BUILD" in the list below and get the version of COM_CNSS_BT_LNX.LA.3.6.1.00.00.032,"32" in this case,expected output is 32 but running into below error?how to fix it?

```
import re
comments = [{u'timestamp': 1403046914, u'message': u'Patch Set 1: Looks good to me, but someone else must approve\n\nThis patchset has been processed by the service.', u'reviewer': {u'username': u'service', u'name': u'service Service Account', u'email': u'service@localhost'}}, {u'timestamp': 1403051700, u'message': u'Patch Set 1: Developer Build and Test COMccessful\n\nINCLUDED IN TEAM_COM_BUILD: COM_CNSS_BT_LNX.LA.3.6.1.00.00.032\n\nhttp://qwiki.company.com/div_wcnss/COM_CNSS_BT_LNX.LA.3.6.1.00.00.032', u'reviewer': {u'username': u'user2', u'name': u'USER Prakash Soy', u'email': u'user2@div.company.com'}}, {u'timestamp': 1403052176, u'message': u'Patch Set 1: Looks good to me, approved\n\n', u'reviewer': {u'username': u'username', u'name': u'Alekhya Damera', u'email': u'username@div.company.com'}}]
matchobj = re.search("INCLUDED IN TEAM_COM_BUILD: (\s*)$", str(comments), re.MULTILINE)
print matchobj
build = matchobj.group(1)
print build

chunks = build.split('.')
print chunks

last_one = chunks[-1]
print last_one
```

Error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "su_version.py", line 5, in <module>
    build = matchobj.group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression is wrong. This one will work:

```
matchobj = re.search(r"INCLUDED IN TEAM_COM_BUILD: \S+\.(\d+)\\n", str(comments))
```

It will greedily match non-whitespace characters after `INCLUDED IN TEAM_COM_BUILD` until it hits a `.` character, followed by one or more digits (which get captured in a match group), followed by a newline. Which is what you want.

**Edit:**

In response to your comment, you can use this to match both patterns:

```
matchobj = re.search(r"INCLUDED IN TEAM_COM_BUILD:\s+\S+?\.(?:\d+\.){5}(\d+)(?:\.\d+)?", str(comments))
```

This matches the first instance (it returns the first instance because we match `\S+` non-greedily, using `\S+?`) of 5 consecutive `<one or more digit>.` groups, followed by one or more digits (which are captured in a group), *optionally* followed by `.<one or more digits>`. The `?:` characters inside of the parenthesis means that the group is non-capturing, and the `?` after the parenthesis marks the group as optional.

Comment: - lets say the tag is "COM_CNSS_BT_LNX.LA.3.6.1.00.00.032.1" ,in this case above log is printing a "1",i still want to print 32,how to do that ?

Comment: @user3682248 I edited my answer to cover that question.